# Filling a combobox in asp net core mvc in razor view

Tags: c#, razor, combobox, asp.net-core-mvc

My code:

```
<label asp-for="FlightDestID"> Select Destination </label>
<select asp-for="FlightDestID">

@foreach (var l in (List<Locations>)ViewBag.Locations)
{
    <option value="@l.ID" label="@l.Name"></option>
}
</select>
```

This code fills the combo with all empty items. I would like that the value be the id of the Location and the name displayed be the name of location.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
<option value="@l.ID">@l.Name</option>
```

this worked!